# UITableView stick tableHeaderView and sectionHeaderView together on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using plain-style `UITableView` with sections, which have sectionView's. So, i will put `UISearchBar` as table-header-view and i need it was always visible on the top, but keep scrollable behaviour when user scroll down.

There's a picture how it looks like

[image]

So, i need to show `HeaderView` between navigation bar and section 2..3..N when scroll. Header view should stick to navigation bar, and section header view should stick to the header view.

[image]

I tried next methods:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect rect = self.tableHeaderView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = MIN(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
    self.tableHeaderView.frame = rect;
}
```

and

```
@implementation MyTableView

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect rect = self.tableHeaderView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = MIN(0, self.contentOffset.y);
    self.tableHeaderView.frame = rect;
}
```

But get no results.

Answer (score 1):

You,Maby don't use `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

and if you want use scrollView In StoryBoard - connect it there,

you could fully show your  code in the class `UITableView`?

and use `ViewDidLoad`!!!